# Border opacity wthout specifing background colour in .NET MAUI app

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a simple, un-themed Maui app. Maui's default colour binding works as expected when I change the Windows theme between dark and light, which is what I want.

I have a `Border` object that is part of a `Grid` layout and which is positioned over some other elements. For visual design reasons I want the other elements to be partly visible through it, so I set its `Opacity` to 0.75. I don't specify its background colour because I want it to use the default for the current system theme. This worked until recently, but now the opacity only seems to be applied if a background colour is also explicitly specified - which I don't want to do for the reason described above. **Is there a way to have a partly-opaque `Border` without hard-coding a background colour?**

The following xaml is a cut-down example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <Border
            Opacity="0.75"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ZIndex="99"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="200"  HeightRequest="100"
            Stroke="white" StrokeThickness="3"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Running this gives me the following result where the `Label` elements are not opaqued by the `Border`:

[image: output with no background colour]

If I change the `Border` element's xaml to include, for example, `BackgroundColor="LightGreen"` then I get the following result, where the `Label` elements *are* opaqued by the `Border`:

[image: output with background colour]

I *do* want the opaqueness but I *don't* want to hard-code a background colour - I want Maui to choose the appropriate one depending on the system theme. **How can I achieve this?** Do I have to theme the app and tightly specify element colours?

(I'm targeting Windows and Mac only using .net 6 in current VS2022 mainline on Win11.)

Comment: You need a background color to have opacity/transparency. Maybe there is a misunderstanding. When you define a border and you set a value for the opacity, this applies to the border and the elements contained therein, but not to the elements that are covered by the border. No color means there's nothing to set an opacity (or transparency) for. You could use the same color for the border that you're using for the background of the page and then set the opacity to a low value to achieve the effect that you're looking for. You can use the `AppThemeBinding` to set the correct color automatically.

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks! Yes, I understand that the opacity refers to the border. I'm just trying to avoid going to the trouble of theming the app just to achieve a simple effect that I previously got for "free". But if I have to do that then I guess I will.

Comment: I wonder how it worked before. How would you have gotten that "for free" unless the border came with a predefined background theme using the `AppThemeBinding`, e.g. in the `Styles.xaml` resources?

Comment: @ewerspej I suspect it may have been a bug that was fixed. Now I understand that Opacity and BackgroundColor are linked, I'll go ahead and theme the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a background color that an opacity can be applied to, you're required to set one, otherwise you'll be setting the opacity for a transparent background, which is pointless.

In order to achieve your goal of covering some content using a `Border`, you could just set the same color to your `Border`'s background as the background of the page. Since you're working with Light and Dark only, assuming that this is set up with the `AppThemeBinding`, you could just do something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
            <Label Text="Hello world!"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <Border
            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}"
            Opacity="0.75"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ZIndex="99"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="200"  HeightRequest="100"
            Stroke="white" StrokeThickness="3"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Essentially, your border just needs to be able to respond to changes to the app theme. You can find more information on how this works in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of using `AppThemeBinding` to conditionally specify resource values like that. Makes sense.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?